# How do I add sliding tabs to android app, that already has nav drawer

Tags: android

I have an app which has a nav drawer already, I want to add some sliding tabs to a couple fragments to limit the content that you have to scroll through.

I am having trouble combining he two (drawer panel and sliding tabs) from examples I've found on the web.

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: It's really really really troublesome to combine the two using only fragments, If you want to use both you will have to use intents.